# Distinct count of one column based on the lack of frequency of another with unique values

Tags: sql, if-statement, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following data in a table

| Transaction date | ID # | Transaction ID # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1st,2021 | 9991 | 158423 |
| Jan 1st,2021 | 9991 | 537912 |
| Jan 1st,2021 | 9988 | 417823 |
| Jan 1st,2021 | 9981 | 659231 |
| Jan 1st,2021 | 9980 | 832239 |

I want to find out the distinct count of the ID #s only when there's only 1 transaction associated with that ID. The transaction ids do not repeat and are all unique as well.

I have this base code here for all distinct values

```
select
    date_trunc('year',transaction_date) as trx_month,
    count (distinct profile_id) as profile_count,
    count (fk_transaction_id) as trx_count,
    count (distinct fk_transaction_id)/count (distinct profile_id) as trx_per_customer
from my_table
group by 1
order by 1;
```

I would like the following output

| Month | Total profiles with only 1 trx |
| --- | --- |
| Jan | 3 |

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT month,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY month) AS cnt
FROM tab
GROUP BY month, ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) = 1;
```

The trick here is to group by two columns month/id, use the HAVING to find only ID per month with one transaction.

Then the value is summed by month using windowed SUM.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=fad8ab96d5fd451f9f6c5eedf78953d2)**

Comment: Thank you - How would I find the count of profile ids of people who have made at least 1 transaction but maybe more than 1?

Comment: @MeganReinhart `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_id) >  1`;

Comment: I tried that and it returns blank results but I know for a fact that in the raw data there are multiple transactions #s connected to singular profile ids :/

Comment: Lukasz answers work in your example data for the `=1` and `>1` variations

Answer (score 2):

Using vanilla `SQL` approach

```
with cte as 

(select month, id
 from tab
 group by month, id
 having count(distinct transaction_id) = 1)

select month, count(id) as single_tranx_id_count
from cte
group by month;
```